# Multiple copies of same email in Email Enabled Library on Sp2010 Foundation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, email

SP2010 Foundation, SQL Server 2008 email enabled library --- I've set these up many time before at other sites, but this symptom is new. New client, new site -- library has "save email" and store in folder using subject. Folder is created, email is stored. Then the message is stored againa nd again... after 250 copies of message stored in folder, I delete the folder from the library. Seconds later, it is re-created and the messages come pouring in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the SharePoint Timer Service don't have full permissions to the drop folder.